# How can i insert select2 data into mysqli database using ajax & codeigniter?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

I wanted to insert multiple selected data into database. When the submit button is clicked. only a single value is being sent to the db. How can i sent all the selected data from the dropdown and stored in the database.

Jquery Code.

```
$("#save_assign_asset").on('click', function(event) {

    //get by value
    var checkout_assets = $('.checkout_assets').val();
    var checkout_department = $('.checkout_department_id 
            option:selected').val();
    var checkout_employee = $('.checkout_employee').val();
    var checkout_branch = $('.checkout_branch_id 
       option:selected').val();
    var checkout_qty = $('.checkout_qty').val();
    var d = new Date();
    var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + 
   "/" + d.getDate();

    var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append("item_id", checkout_assets);
    fd.append("department_id", checkout_department);
    fd.append("employee_id", checkout_employee);
    fd.append("branch_id", checkout_branch);
    fd.append("qty", checkout_qty);
    fd.append("date_assigned", strDate);

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>checkouts/create",
        type: "post",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.res == "success") {
                toastr["success"](response.message);
                $("#checkout_asset_form").modal("hide");
        
            } else {
                toastr["error"](response.message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Controller code

```
public function create()
{
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

        

   $ajax_data = $this->input->post();
   
        if ($this->Checkout_model- 
      >create_checkout_asset($ajax_data)) {
            $data = array('res' => "success", 'message' => "Data 
   added");
        } else {
            $data = array('res' => "error", 'message' => "Failed 
   to 
  add data");
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
        echo "No direct script access allowed";
    }
}
```

Model Code

```
function create_checkout_asset($ajax_data)
{
    
    return $this->db->insert('tblitememployeeassignment', 
 $ajax_data);
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="checkout_modal" role="dialog" 
   tabindex="-1" aria- 
       labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" 
 id="exampleModalLabel">Checkout Asset</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data- 
   dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_open('checkouts/create', 
  'id=checkout_asset_form'); ?>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label 
  for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Checkout to: </label>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio 
  custom-control-inline">
                        <input id="checkout_employee" 
  type="radio" name="radio-inline" 
              class="custom-control-input"><span class="custom- 
  control- 
       label">Employee</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio 
    custom-control-inline">
                        <input id="checkout_department" 
   type="radio" name="radio-inline" 
            checked="" class="custom-control-input"><span 
           class="custom-control- 
             label">Department</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="checkout_assets">Assets</label>
                    <select class="checkout_assets form-control" 
             multiple="multiple" 
             name="checkout_assets_id[]">
                        <option value="">Select Asset</option>
                        <?php foreach ($items as $asset) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo 
                  $asset['item_id']; ?>"><?php echo 
                     $asset['item_name']; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group department col-md-6">
                        <label 
            for="checkout_department_id">Department</label>
                        <select name="checkout_department_id" 
                          class="checkout_department_id form- 
           control">
                            <option value="">Select 
           Department</option>
                            <?php foreach ($departments as 
          $department) : ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo 
             $department['department_id']; 
                               ?>"><?php echo 
               $department['department']; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6" 
              id="search_employee-form">
                        <label 
           for="search_employee">Employee</label>
                        <select class="checkout_employee form- 
               control" 
                                name="checkout_employee" 
          id="checkout_employee">
                            <option value="">Select an 
             Employee</option>
                            <?php foreach ($employees as 
          $employee) : ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo 
           $employee['id']; ?>"><?php 
                               echo $employee['employee_name']; ? 
                      ></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputAddress">Location</label>
                    <select name="checkout_branch_id" 
                 class="checkout_branch_id form- 
                            control">
                        <option value="">Select Location</option>
                        <?php foreach ($branches as $branch) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo 
                        $branch['branch_id']; ?>"><?php 
                        echo $branch['location']; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="checkout_qty">Quantity</label>
                    <input type="number" class="checkout_qty 
                     form-control" 
                name="checkout_qty" placeholder="Quantity">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="remarks">Remarks</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                  name="remarks" 
                  placeholder="Detail Description">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
             dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" name="save_assign_asset" 
          id="save_assign_asset" 
         class="btn btn-primary">Assign Asset</button>
        </div>
        </form>
         </div>
           </div>
          </div>
```

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3TWb.png)

Please help I am new to this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**
Form data will be send in the ajax like this.You can get the all form fields.

```
var formData = new FormData($('#checkout_asset_form')[0]);
          $.ajax({
                url : url,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
               
                success:function(data)
                {
                   }
                });
```